# HTC one - app is killed every time

Tags: android, memory-management, service

Hi I got a problem with my app. App is tracking the user road by GPS. It getting only start point and with each next point calculate distance and increase time. Everything is working great on my HTC Wildfire (with CMD7 2.3.7), Samsung SIII and Galaxy Tab 10.1.

When user start tracking, the app is finishing current activity and start new process with service in background. In the same time start new activity with small animation and put ongoing status in notification area. Everything cool, but problem starts the user is trying app on HTC one series. I can't describle how it behave, cause I don't have this phone and can't reproduce the bug.

Any of you heard anything about memory managing in HTC sense? I read some article that HTC one has this kind a feature.

Or it there is any way to test particular device on emulator?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: "I can't describle how it behave, cause I don't have this phone and can't reproduce the bug." Go to a carrier store and install your app and SendLog. Once it crashes send yourself the log so you can get a stacktrace. Is going to be nigh impossible to debug without some more info.

Comment: there is the problem, app is not crashing. It got ACRA and I don't get any info.

Comment: how did this issue come to your attention? Did the person who told you tell you anything about how it was behaving other than something like "it doesn't work"?

Comment: service is using Application instance to share data. After someone finish his/her tracking got zero results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are calling the Service#startForeground method to give your Service foreground scheduling priority. You can find it documented on the Service class:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

I have seen background services not get killed by using this on the One series.

Comment: I will try set up my service as a foreground.